# Wrong result getting when comparing decimal type values in mysql

Tags: mysql

I am trying to fetch prod where `low_stock_alert > stock_type`.

Both low_Stock_alert, stock_type Type decimal(10,2).

Why am I getting the wrong result.
Wrong result : id => 368, 361, 339

```
SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE `low_stock_alert` > `stock_type` 
ORDER BY `products`.`id` DESC
LIMIT 0 , 50
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In all the records you indeed have `low_stock_alert > stock_type`. Presumably, though, this isn't what you intended - you probably wanted to query `low_stock_alert > stock`:

```
SELECT   * 
FROM     `products` 
WHERE    `low_stock_alert` > `stock` 
ORDER BY `products`.`id` DESC
LIMIT     0, 50
```

Comment: Thnkx for your help. i have posted one more question.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27086418/getting-wrong-result-when-using-cakephp-association-in-paginaton