# Getting Wrong result when using CakePHP Query

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I am trying to fetch Product where Low stock > Stock.

Why i am getting  Wrong results in CakePHP Query ?

Using CakePHP Custom query it is working fine. but with default pagination query result are wrong.

I have association between Product and Category Model.

**Controller code :**

```
$condition = array('Product.status =' => 1, 'Product.is_deleted !=' => 1, 
'Product.low_stock_alert != ' => 0, 'Product.low_stock_alert >' => 'Product.stock');

    $this->paginate = array('fields' => array('Product.id', 'Product.name',
'Product.code', 'Product.stock_type','Product.low_stock_alert',
'Product.stock','category.name'),'conditions' => $condition, 'limit' => Configure::read('LIST_PROD_NUM_RECORDS'),'order' => 'Product.id ASC');
```

**Query Generating :**

```
SELECT `Product`.`id`, `Product`.`name`, `Product`.`code`, `Product`.`stock_type`,
`Product`.`stock`, `category`.`name` FROM `shopping`.`products` AS `Product` LEFT 
JOIN `shopping`.`categories` AS `Category` ON (`Product`.`category_id` = 
`Category`.`id`) LEFT JOIN `shopping`.`users` AS `AddedBy` ON (`Product`.`added_by` 
= `AddedBy`.`id`) LEFT JOIN `shopping`.`users` AS `ModifiedBy` ON 
(`Product`.`modified_by` = `ModifiedBy`.`id`) WHERE `Product`.`status` = 1 AND 
`Product`.`is_deleted` != 1 AND `Product`.`low_stock_alert` != 0 AND 
`Product`.`low_stock_alert` > 'Product.stock' ORDER BY `Product`.`id` ASC LIMIT 100
```

**Model -> Product.php**

```
class Product extends AppModel {

    public $name = 'Product';
    public $cacheQueries = false;
    public $actsAs = array('Containable');
    public $belongsTo = array(
        'Category' => array(
            'className' => 'Category',
            'foreignKey' => 'category_id',
            'fields' => array('name', 'description', 'stock_type', 'qrt_per', 'half_per', 'three_forth_per')
        ),
        'AddedBy' => array(
            'className' => 'User',
            'foreignKey' => 'added_by',
            'fields' => array('first_name', 'last_name', 'email')
        ),
        'ModifiedBy' => array(
            'className' => 'User',
            'foreignKey' => 'modified_by',
            'fields' => array('first_name', 'last_name', 'email')
        )
    );
}
```

**Model -> Category.php**

```
class Category extends AppModel {
    var $name = 'Category';
    public $cacheQueries = false;
    public $belongsTo = array(
        'AddedBy' => array(
            'className' => 'User',
            'foreignKey' => 'added_by',
            'fields' => array('first_name', 'last_name', 'email')
        ),
        'ModifiedBy' => array(
            'className' => 'User',
            'foreignKey' => 'modified_by',
            'fields' => array('first_name', 'last_name', 'email')
        )
    );
    public $hasMany = array(
        'Product' => array(
            'className' => 'Product',
            'order' => 'Product.created DESC'
        )
    );
}
```

**Wrong Result:**

[image]

But with this below Custom Query i am getting accurate result:

```
 $data = $this->Product->Query("SELECT products.*, categories.name, categories.description, categories.stock_type, categories.qrt_per, categories.half_per, categories.three_forth_per, AddedBy.first_name, AddedBy.last_name, AddedBy.email, ModifiedBy.first_name, ModifiedBy.last_name, ModifiedBy.email FROM sunnaair_kaziDB.products AS products LEFT JOIN sunnaair_kaziDB.categories AS categories ON (products.category_id = categories.id) LEFT JOIN sunnaair_kaziDB.users AS AddedBy ON (products.added_by = AddedBy.id) LEFT JOIN sunnaair_kaziDB.users AS ModifiedBy ON (products.modified_by = ModifiedBy.id) WHERE products.status = 1 AND products.is_deleted != 1 AND products.low_stock_alert != 0 AND products.low_stock_alert > products.stock ORDER BY products.id ASC LIMIT 50");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is with this condition:

```
'Product.low_stock_alert >' => 'Product.stock'
```

In Cake, '`Product.stock`' is not read as a table name but as a literal string. Please see the subtle error in the generated SQL:

```
AND `Product`.`low_stock_alert` > 'Product.stock'
```

To fix it, please try changing the condition to:

```
'Product.low_stock_alert > Product.stock'
```

So the whole line becomes:

```
 $condition = array('Product.status =' => 1, 'Product.is_deleted !=' => 1, 
'Product.low_stock_alert != ' => 0, 'Product.low_stock_alert > Product.stock');
```

Remember the following: `=>` is for escaping. Don't use this when comparing columns to columns. You could even just dump using `=>` all together for these conditions as there is no vector for an SQL injection attack here.

Comment: Hey James .. i appreciate your efforts. This problem takes my lot of time.Thankx